# I want to create a form to enter pet owner and his pets details

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a website for pets . I wish to create a page where pet owner can register and add his pets. I have made a form and put javascript to add more pets , which creates new fields when click on "Add more pet" link. But I am unable to collect this information into php variables. Link is here : http://animalswecare.in/mypet.php

I have working knowledge of php and mysqli.

My php code
                   if ( isset( $_POST['mypet'] ) ) {

```
   $name         = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['name'] ) )  );
  $email     = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['email'] ) )  );
  $password    = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['password'] ) )  );
   $gender       = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['sex'] ) )  );
     $contact     = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['contact'] ) )  );
   $country     = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['country'] ) )  );
    $state       = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['state'] ) )  );
  $city        = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['city'] ) )  );
   //$photo       = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['picture'] ) )  );

 $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, $_FILES['picture']['name'] );
            $ext=$_FILES['picture']['name'];
            $targetpath = "images/user/big/";

            if($ext !="")
            {
        $ext = explode(".",$ext);
        if($ext[1]=="jpg" || $ext[1]=="gif" || $ext[1]=="jpeg" || $ext[1]=="png" || $ext[1]=="bmp" || $ext[1]=="wbmp" || $ext[1]=="JPEG" || $ext[1]=="JPG" || $ext[1]=="GIF" || $ext[1]=="PNG" || $ext[1]=="BMP")
        {   
            if($_FILES['picture']['size'] <= 2000000)
            {

                $filename=$targetpath.$id."-" .$fname;
                $photo = $id."-" .$fname;
                if (file_exists($filename)) 
                {
                    chmod($filename, 0777); 
                    unlink($filename); 
                }
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'],$filename))
                {
                    $thpath = "images/user/thumb/";
                    $file = createThumb1($filename, $thpath, $fl_db,350,280);
                }
            }
        }
     }

  $query = "INSERT INTO `user` SET `name`= '$name',`email` = '$email' ,`password` = '$password',`gender` = '$gender', `contact` = '$contact', `country` = '$country', `state` = '$state', `city` = '$city', `photo` = '$photo',`date` = now(),`status` = '1' ";
  $insComm = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  $uid = mysqli_insert_id( $dbc );

 if($_POST['petname'])
 {
 $array = $_POST['petname'];
 foreach($array as $petname)
 {
 if(strlen($petname)>0)
 {

 //$petname    = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['petname'] ) )  );
  $type     = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['type'] ) )  );
  $breed    = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['breed'] ) )  );
  $gender   = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['gender'] ) )  );
  //$photo      = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, strip_tags ( trim ( $_POST['photo'] ) )  );

  $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, $_FILES['petimage']['name'] );
            $ext=$_FILES['petimage']['name'];
            $targetpath = "images/pet/big/";

            if($ext !="")
            {
        $ext = explode(".",$ext);
        if($ext[1]=="jpg" || $ext[1]=="gif" || $ext[1]=="jpeg" || $ext[1]=="png" || $ext[1]=="bmp" || $ext[1]=="wbmp" || $ext[1]=="JPEG" || $ext[1]=="JPG" || $ext[1]=="GIF" || $ext[1]=="PNG" || $ext[1]=="BMP")
        {   
            if($_FILES['petimage']['size'] <= 2000000)
            {

                $filename=$targetpath.$id."-" .$fname;
                $petphoto = $id."-" .$fname;
                if (file_exists($filename)) 
                {
                    chmod($filename, 0777); 
                    unlink($filename); 
                }
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['petimage']['tmp_name'],$filename))
                {
                    $thpath = "images/pet/thumb/";
                    $file = createThumb1($filename, $thpath, $fl_db,350,280);
                }
            }
        }
      }
  $query = "INSERT INTO `mypet` SET `uid`= '$uid',`petname`= '$petname',`type` =        '$type',`breed` = '$breed',`gender` = '$gender', `photo` = '$petphoto',`date` = now(),`status` = '1' "; 
   $insComm = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); 
   $msg = "Your information is successfully Added!!";
```

Comment: Can we see the PHP code you've got so far?

Comment: @andrewsi php code added

Comment: And what seems to not be working?

Comment: @andrewsi For one, he is accounting for multiple pet names, but not multiple breeds, types, or genders.  Neither in his PHP nor his HTML.

Comment: @EricH wanted to check first so added only pet names and it is not working.

Comment: @user995426 Then I would recommend what Oliver Tappin suggested below: run `print_r($_POST)` to see what data you *are* receiving and what format it is in.

Comment: @EricH Thanks 4 help . Its late night here 2am goin 2 sleep, will try tmrw and get back.

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATED

Your petname fields HTML is set up with the proper attributes for the duplicate entries (`name="petname[]"`), **but your type, gender, and breed inputs need to have `[]` at the end of their name attributes**: `<input type="text" name="type[]">`.

On the PHP side you should see, in your `POST` (or `GET` if your form method is `GET`) array, something like this: `$_POST["petname"][0]` and `$_POST["petname"][1]`.  So I would do something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST["petname"] as $name)
{
    // store $name in the database
}


foreach ($_POST["type"] as $type)
{
    // store $type in the database
}

etc...
```

Since you are using multiple fields, you may want to structure them like so:

```
<input type="text" name="pet[name][]">
<input type="text" name="pet[type][]">
```

Then you could do the following:

```
foreach ($_POST["pet"] as $pet)
{
    // store $pet["name"] in the database
    // store $pet["type"] in the database
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: You are accounting for multiple pet names, but not multiple pet breeds, types, and genders.  I have edited my post as I found some errors in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to view your `$_POST` data is like this:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Then you'll be able to find out whether there are any errors but without any PHP code, we can't tell you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` will contain the data received from the form:

`$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['email']`, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

```
$petname = $_POST['form controls name']
```

$_POST contains data received by a form when the method is post, the equivalent is $_GET[' '] by default.